# SUM multiplied by number of rows (query with joins)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I read some topics regarding this problem, but I couldn't find a way to use the solutions in my code. From what I understand, I'm doing joins wrong.

I have a bunch of contacts in Hubspot CRM with source marked as Adwords campaign. I want to calculate the cost of lead acquisition by dividing spend for ads in this campaign by number of leads generated.

The problem is, sum spent on ads is being multiplied by number of leads from given campaign.

```
SELECT Sum("adwords"."adwords"."adcost")                           AS 
       "sum", 
       "adwords"."adwords"."campaign"                              AS 
       "campaign", 
       Count(DISTINCT "hubspot_stitch"."contacts"."properties__email__value") AS 
       "Leads", 
       Sum("adwords"."adwords"."adcost") / Count(DISTINCT 
       "hubspot_stitch"."contacts"."properties__email__value")                AS 
       "Cost Per Acquisition" 
FROM   "adwords"."adwords" 
       INNER JOIN "hubspot_stitch"."contacts" 
               ON Lower("adwords"."adwords"."campaign") = 
"hubspot_stitch"."contacts"."properties__hs_analytics_source_data_1__value" 
AND ( ( 
"hubspot_stitch"."contacts"."properties__hs_analytics_source_data_2__value" 
      LIKE 
      'sales_adwords%' ) 
          AND ( 
    "hubspot_stitch"."contacts"."properties__lifecyclestage__value" = 
    'opportunity' 
     OR "hubspot_stitch"."contacts"."properties__lifecyclestage__value" 
        = 
        'customer' ) ) 
GROUP  BY "adwords"."adwords"."campaign" 
ORDER  BY "adwords"."adwords"."campaign" ASC
```

This is the result I receive (example numbers to not lose my job):

```
Sum        | Campaign       | Leads | Cost Per Acquisition
700,000.00 | [S] mobiledev  | 7     | 100,000.00
```

But the real Sum should equal 100,000.00 (7 times less)

```
Sum        | Campaign       | Leads | Cost Per Acquisition
100,000.00 | [S] mobiledev  | 7     | 14,285.71
```

Comment: Have you tried just SELECT * FROM  (without the SUMs etc) just to see what your query generates?

Comment: Yes, I did. Adwords data is just a table of every ad per row, with columns such as `campaign` and `ad cost`. I want to sum `ad cost` grouped by `campaign` and divide that by number of contacts from hubspot with `data_source_1 == campaign`

Comment: Just make the join an inner query where you sum your leads. Then you shouldn't need sum clauses on the primary select statement

Comment: @user3532232 can you be more specific? I don't really understand what you just wrote

Answer (score 1):

So I don't really know how your data looks like but i'm guessing something lkne this might work. Tsql syntax though:

```
Select (sum(t1.adcost)/count(*)) 'sum' 
  , t1.campaign
  , count(*) 'leads' 
  , (sum(t1.adcost)/count(*))/count(*) 
From (select a.campaign, sum(adCost) ''adcost' from adwords a group by a. Campaign ) t1
-- the rest of your code
```

God i hate coding on the phone. 
Any how my commenTip was a bit wrong i figured after i wrote this. But this should do it

Comment: Thanks! I was pretty sure the solution was kind of sophisticated, but that did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Do the sum in the separate query without `JOIN`

```
SELECT AD."sum",
       AD."campaign",
       Count(DISTINCT CT."properties__email__value") AS "Leads", 
       AD."sum" / Count(DISTINCT CT."properties__email__value") AS "Cost Per Acquisition" 
FROM
(
    SELECT Sum(AD."adcost")  AS "sum", 
           AD."campaign" AS "campaign"
    FROM   "adwords"."adwords" as AD
    GROUP  BY AD."campaign" 
) as AD
INNER JOIN "hubspot_stitch"."contacts" CT
               ON Lower(AD."campaign") = CT."properties__hs_analytics_source_data_1__value" AND 
( 
    CT."properties__hs_analytics_source_data_2__value" LIKE 'sales_adwords%'  AND 
    ( 
       CT."properties__lifecyclestage__value" = 'opportunity' OR 
       CT."properties__lifecyclestage__value" = 'customer' 
    ) 
) 
GROUP  BY AD."campaign" 
ORDER  BY AD."campaign" ASC
```